# Validation and Exception Handling

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I am trying to validate a control in WPF and show the Exception message in ControlTemplate that i have designed, but when i run the application the logic works fine but instead of seeing the Exception message in control template, the application breaks and throws the exception message which is supposed to be shown in the ControlTemplate. i am posting my code below, someone please tell me what am i doing wrong.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <TextBox Width="200" Margin="5" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorTemplate}" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" >
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <ExceptionValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</StackPanel>
```

app.xaml

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxErrorTemplate">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                   Foreground="Orange" 
                   FontSize="12pt"></TextBlock>
        <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The Person.cs Class

```
public class Person
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name {
        get { return _name;}
        set {
            _name = value;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_name))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Name is mandatory");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Person p = new Person();
    p.Name="faisal";
    this.DataContext = p;
}
```

Instead of showing the Exception message in the Control template defined it shows the message as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please try throwing the Exception in getter not setter. Somewhere I've seen an example where this works.

Comment: But i am trying to set the value if the value is valid ( i mean if it passes the validation) so i am not sure i understand why should i do it in getter. can you elaborate .thanks

Comment: I could not reproduce with studio 2012 - everything worked fine. 
Only the textblock in the control panel should probably have text bound to [0].Exception.Message.
Btw. why did you wrap the main textblock in adornerdecorator?

Comment: I have just given it a border. that is why and i think it was an issue with VS2010 this error was solved when i upgraded my VS.